# Java 8 lambda returning an empty list of map keys based on a filter applied to map objects

Tags: java, spring, list, lambda, java-8

I'm currently playing with Java 8 lambda's and having a small issue.

**What I want to do**

I have a built a prototype website using spring, it takes in a transaction object and stores it in a map. The transaction class has a long value and String type (e.g. hotel).
What I'm trying to do is, run a lambda expression that filters out all of the transaction objects which have a certain type and return a List which is the list of their keys.

Basically I just want to see a list of the keys to objects in the map which have a specific type.

**Simple test**
I have tested it by filling in an object which has a type of car and a value of 3000. I then passed in car on the web form to filter the map based on this. I outputted what the input type is (to check the webform received it correctly), the type stored in Map object and if they're equal which is all correct, however the lambda is still returning an empty list.

I have the code written as below:

**Offending Method:**

```
    HashMap<Long, Transaction> transactionMap = new HashMap<>();

@RequestMapping(value = "transactionservice/types/{type}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Long>> getSameType(@PathVariable String type) {

    System.out.println("Input type is: " + type);
    System.out.println("What is stored at 1: " + transactionMap.get(Integer.toUnsignedLong(1)).getType());
    System.out.println("Values are equal: " + type.equals(transactionMap.get(Integer.toUnsignedLong(1)).getType()));

    List<Long> listSameType = transactionMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getValue().getType() == type)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("List size of keys: " + listSameType.size());

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Long>>(listSameType, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input type is: car
What is stored at 1: car
Values are equal: true
List size of keys: 0
```

---

Comment: There is your bug: ```s.getValue().getType() == type``` Was this a typo?

Comment: Well I'm hugely embarrassed. Thanks very much, kicking myself that I didn't spot that, after spending a couple of hours looking over lambda documentation thinking it was an issue with that side of my knowledge.

Again, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the equality check for `String` fails:

```
List<Long> listSameType = transactionMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getValue().getType().equals(type))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Use `equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: As said, above,  
Thats me hugely embarrassed. Thanks very much for spotting that and taking the time to answer.

Comment: Happens to the best :)